# Pass class method as callback in Silex

Tags: php, callback, silex

Is it possible to pass class/object methods as callbacks in Silex? For example I have this code:

```
class Implementation {
 public function test() {
   return "Hello World!";
 }
}

$code = new Implementation();
$app->get('/', function() use ($code) {
 return $code->test();
});
```

As I don't want the code within the anonymous callback I've moved it into a class. This works, however I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to write this, something like:

```
$app->get('/', $code->test);
```

So far I haven't found anything so if anyone of you has an idea it's really appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [Controllers in Classes](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#controllers-in-classes):

```
$app->get('/', 'Acme\\Foo::bar');

use Silex\Application;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

namespace Acme
{
  class Foo
  {
    public function bar(Request $request, Application $app)
    {
        // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Vielen Dank! :) I have no idea how I missed this ... probably as I was looking for it in PHP, not Silex ...